# Kafka events not receiving from all topic when multiple topics are subscribed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Using Spring kafka i created a consumer, I have 3 topics and consumer is successfully subscribing to all topics. But Im receiving events only from one topic. When i try consumer with single topic it's working for all topics. But when I use a single consumer for all topics its only receiving events for one topic, and this topic is not consistent. My config will look like below

`Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>(); configs.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, config.getServers()); configs.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, config.getGroup()); configs.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class); configs.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class); configs.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);`

Event listener annotation is

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.consumer.topic}'.split(',')}", groupId = "${kafka.consumer.group}")
```

Comment: Are you using a unique consumer group name not running elsewhere? Can you please show a [mcve]?

Comment: Show your code and configuration; if you see all the partitions in the `partitions assigned` log meessage then you should see any new records published to all those partitions. For a new consumer (one that has never committed an offset for a particular partition), you need `auto.offset.reset=earliest` to see records that are already in the topic(s).

Comment: Im using unique consumer group name which is not used anywhere, auto.offset.reset is not set so it will be latest, no issues with that. Also im getting log that all subscribed to all my partitions and topics.